# $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos a x}{b^2 + x^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{2 b} e^{- b |a|}$

Tags: real-analysis

With the definition of the Fourier transform
$$
\hat{f}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) e^{- 2 \pi i x y} \, dy
$$
I have shown that
$$
\hat{f}(x) = 2 \int_0^{\infty} f(y) \cos(2 \pi x y) \, dy
$$
for all $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, being $f$ an even function. Also, if we define $f : x \mapsto \frac{\pi}{b} e^{- 2 \pi b |x|}$, $b > 0$, on $\mathbb{R}$, I have shown that $\hat{f}(x) = \frac{1}{b^2 + x^2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Using these two statements, I have to show that
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos a x}{b^2 + x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2 b} e^{- b |a|}
$$
for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $b \in (0 , \infty)$. I have tried but I haven't got anything. Can you help me?

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Help me to show the equality of the title.

Comment: Did you not just prove that yourself?

Comment: I couldn't. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Fourier Inversion Theorem we have

$$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i2\pi xy}\hat f(y)\,dy$$

If $\hat f(y)=\frac{1}{b^2+y^2}$, then $f(x)=\frac\pi be^{-2\pi b|x|}$.  Hence, by exploiting symmetry, we have

$$\frac\pi be^{-2\pi b|x|}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-i2\pi xy}}{b^2+y^2}\,dy=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi xy)}{b^2+y^2}\,dy$$

whereupon division by $2$ and setting $x=\frac a{2\pi}$ yields the coveted result.

Comment: But your equality depends of $x$

Comment: Set $x=a/(2\pi)$.  I've edited to add this.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark